# Multiprocessing/threading in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having some trouble with multiprocessing in my program. Hopefully you can follow.

I have a script that pulls information out of my database and for each entry received it runs a script that doesn't end. It checks and check and checks and doesn't end. lol

I also have another script that does the same thing. Pull database entries and check and check and check.... No end

I have 3 more of the same scripts.

I was planning on having a multiprocessing script start this process by creating 5 processes. From these 5 processes each process would run the "for each entry" check and check and check. However, because each entry runs indefinitely, I need to create a new process for each entry.

Ex. 10 entries in 1st database. 1st process runs 10 separate processes that check and check and check. 5 entries in 2nd database. 2nd process runs 5 separate processes that check and check....

How do I do this in python if each of the 5 main processes need separate smaller processes?

This is one of the 5 multiprocessing scripts:

```
my_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() # queue to store our values
stop_event = multiprocessing.Event() # flag which signals processes to stop
my_pool = None

def my_function(foo):
    print("starting %s" % foo)
    try:
        add.build(foo)
    except Exception,e: 
        print str(e)

MAX_PROCESSES = 50
my_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)

x = VAR.objects.order_by('name').values('name)
for t in x:
    t = t.values()[0]
    my_pool.apply_async(my_function, args=(t,))
my_pool.close()
my_pool.join()
```

Now how do I tie 4 of these scripts together to be started with one script?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you have the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=python&query=multiprocessing

Comment: @dashiell Right now I've tried to have a script that starts 5 processes. From their the function that the first process starts is another multiprocessing script. But this doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you should get things running non-indefinitely before using more resources? Reading this seems like an XY problem, and without context or code there isn't much help we can give.

Comment: I have each of the 5 main processes running perfectly when I execute them separately using a multiprocessing script. Now I need to tie all 5 separate scripts together into one script.

Comment: @Delioth I posted some code that works perfectly if run on its own. This starts process "my_function" then "add.build(foo)" runs forever... Everything is GTG. The other 4 scripts are very similar. All run perfectly when run by them selves. Now how do I tie them all together?